# bison: one error causes additional but incorrect error

Tags: error-handling, bison

In the class section of my code, if I write an error a few lines will be reported as errors when they should not. I put '`| error`' in certain locations where it's good/safe to recover from errors but I don't think it's using it. Maybe it's trying to resume mid expression someplace?

Is there a way I can force Bison to try to recover in designated locations? How does it work and what might I be doing wrong?

I put the error line next to the loop. Here is an example:

```
SomeRuleLoop:
    | Rule ',' SomeRuleLoop
Rule:
      A
    | B
    | C
    | Error
A:
      AA AAB AABC
    | AA AAB AABC Z
...
```

---

Here is an example of my rules. I see "funcBody error" in my console however the next line gets an error because of the first error. Even though each funcBodyRule is standalone.

```
funcBodyLoop:
    | funcBodyLoop funcBody

funcBody:
      funcBodyRule
    | error { printf("funcBody error"); $$=0; }
    | '#' EQ { printf("still in funcBody\n"); $$=0; }
```

I tried writing #== between the line with the first error and the line with the 2nd. I wrote this to check if the parser is still in the funcbody loop. <strike>This doesnt give an error so it is</strike>. Nevermind i added a printf and the string isnt printed so maybe it isnt in the function loop anymore? how do i fix this?

Comment: It is going to be nigh on impossible to help much without some code to help us.  **But** it needs to be close to minimal code, not several hundred lines..

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Its where the loop is. I modified my question

Comment: You know that Yacc (Bison) is case sensitive, so the alternative with 'Error' is not the same as 'error' (which is 'built in' and has a specific meaning w.r.t error recovery).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Ok noted. I checked and i dont use 'Error' anywhere, only 'error'

Comment: Send me the code - see my profile; I'll see if I can make head or tail of the problem.  The fragment here is not sufficient to go on, I fear.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: The cut down version appears to handle the error fine. I'll chalk the problem up to weirdness with shift/reduce conflicts. Theres <15 and the code is @(a,b,c) with the error on ')' which makes no sense because @( is only used as parameters with a ')' ending it. I'll assume its problem with conflicts and fix that another day

Comment: OK - good luck with resolving the issue.  Conflicts can be exasperating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forcing ';' or newlines at the end of the error solves it. (`| error my_end_of_statenent` instead of `| error`)

Answer (score 1):

Yacc and Bison normally use left-recursive rules, and the rules shown are not left-recursive.

As shown, the first rule is equivalent to:

```
SomeRuleLoop:
        /* Nothing */
    |   Rule ',' SomeRuleLoop
    ;
```

This is a right-recursive rule which says that a 'SomeRuleLoop' is either an empty string of tokens or a 'Rule' followed by a comma and some more 'SomeRuleLoop'.  Note that this means a 'SomeRuleLoop' ends with a comma, which is probably not what you had in mind.

The first rule should probably read:

```
SomeRuleLoop:
        Rule
    |   SomeRuleLoop ',' Rule
    ;
```

Note that allowing for empty alternatives is important - but adding them everywhere tends to make the grammar ambiguous (more shift/reduce conflicts)

---

You also need to use the token 'error' (all lower case) rather than 'Error' (mixed case) to indicate a point where error recovery can occur.

However, I'm not sure what the rest of your troubles are...

Comment: Wait wait wait... your kidding me. Its left recursive? NOT right recursive? Yikes, i have been doing this wrong. That may fix the error problem. I'll comment when i fixed everything

Comment: I am quite confused. I modified the rules to be left recursive. I see my error msg being printed. Yet i still get an error. I updated the question